# How to suscribe to new messages in chat made with Firebase Realtime DB and ReactNative?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am building a ReactNative app that includes a chat, the database that I am using to persist the data is Realtime DB from Firebase.

When I navigate to the chat screen, first I load the already existing messages of the chat once:

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState();
  ...

  let chatRef = firebase.database().ref('chats/' + chatId);
  let chatData = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    chatRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        ...

        chatData = snapshot.val();
        setMessages(chatData.messages.reverse());

        ...
      } else {
        console.log("No data available");
      }
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  },[]);
```

I am using **.once** method on the reference but still, I have to use useEffect to avoid an infinite loop, since I set the chat messages in the state, what triggers the screen to be printed again and the **.once** method would be called again otherwise.

But my problem comes when I want the new messages that arrive to the database, to be shown in realtime in the already open chat screen. For this purpose I have tried to do the following:

```
let messagesRef = chatRef.child('messages');

messagesRef.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  if(snapshot.key > chatLen){
    console.log("NEW MESSAGE IN THIS CHAT: "+data.text);
    let auxMessages = messages;
    auxMessages[-1] = data;
    setMessages(auxMessages)
  }else{
    console.log("REPEATED NOTIFICATION OF MESSAGE: "+data.text);
  }
});
```

Being the **snapshot.key** the number of the message for which I just received an event, and **chatLen** the length of the chat already shown on the screen.

With this last piece of code I try to suscribe to the creation of new messages, if I receive a duplicated event for a message I just ignore it (but I would like to know why this happens), but if it is a new message I want to update what it is shown on the screen, so I add it to the messages in the state, but then I enter in an infinte loop which I don't know how to break, because I don't know how to put another useEffect clause in a way that my screen subscribes to new messages but it doesn't do it every time that the screen gets printed, but at the same time, every time that a new event arrives it is processed by the code in the last 'if' clause.

Sorry for my english, any advice would be apreciated, it is my first time using firebase realtime database references and I may be doing or understanding something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use realtime listeners and a limit of elements you want to get to the `ref`. That way you sould always get only the last 20 elements for example:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState();

let chatRef = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("chats/" + chatId)
  .limitToLast(20);
let chatData = null;

useEffect(() => {
  chatRef.on("child_added", (data) => {
    setMessages({ ...messages, [data.key]: data.val() });
  });

  chatRef.on("child_changed", (data) => {
    setMessages({ ...messages, [data.key]: data.val() });
  });

  chatRef.on("child_removed", (data) => {
    const { [data.key]: removed, ...rest } = messages;
    setMessages(rest);
  });

  //Turn off listener when leaving react component
  return () => chatRef.off();
}, []);

Object.entries(messages)
  .sort(([a], [b]) => {
    // sort object elements by key string value
    return ("" + a.attr).localeCompare(b.attr);
  })
  .map((e) => {
    const [key, val] = e;
    // key your message database key
    // val your message value
  });
```

You could also store the data directly to an array and add, update and remove the elements by searching for the corresponding `key`.

Make sure to turn off the listeners when leaving the component.

Comment: Thank you Tarik, I will try both things, the limitToLast and specially the "turning off" the listener, that I think that could be the solution. I promise to post the results.